# Using specs2 and FakeApplication() to test database fails evolution inserts

Tags: scala, testing, playframework, playframework-2.0, specs2

This is for Play! Framework 2.0.

I'm trying to write a simple test case to ensure my user model is functioning properly and persisting data in my database.  I'd like to run it in memory if possible so I can get a fresh start with every new run.

The issue I have is that my evolutions run(tables are created, data is inserted, but I can't query it as being there).  First, my code.

```
CREATE TABLE user_data (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
user_name varchar(256) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
email varchar(256) NOT NULL,
password varchar(256) NOT NULL,
edits int NOT NULL,
reports int NOT NULL,
active BOOLEAN NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO user_data(user_name, email, password, edits, reports, active) VALUES ('user1', 'user1@email.com', '12345678', 0, 0, true);
```

In application.conf

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/ME"
```

In build.scala

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  // Add your project dependencies here,
    "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4"
)
```

The test code

```
class User_dataSpec extends Specification {

  "The Database" should {
    "persist data properly" in {
  running(FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase())) {

      //User_data.findAll().length must beEqualTo(1)
      //Create users
      User_data.create("user1", "password1", "email@test1.com") must beEqualTo(1)
      User_data.create("user2", "password2", "email@test2.com") must beEqualTo(2)
      User_data.create("user1", "password3", "email@test3.com") must beEqualTo(0)

      //Count users
      User_data.findAll().length must beEqualTo(2)

      //Verify users exist
      User_data.exists("user1") must beTrue
      User_data.exists("user2") must beTrue

      //Verify user doesn't exist
      User_data.exists("user3") must beFalse

      //Find users by ID
      User_data.findUser(1).get.user_name must beEqualTo("user1")
      User_data.findUser(2).get.user_name must beEqualTo("user2")

      //Fail to find users by ID
      User_data.findUser(3) must beNone

      //Find users by user_name
      User_data.findUser("user1").get.user_name must beEqualTo("user1")
      User_data.findUser("user2").get.user_name must beEqualTo("user2")

      //Fail to find users by user_name
      User_data.findUser("user3") must beNone

      //Authenticate users
      User_data.authenticate("user1", "password1") must beTrue
      User_data.authenticate("user2", "password2") must beTrue

      //Fail to authenticate users
      User_data.authenticate("user1", "password2") must beFalse
      User_data.authenticate("user3", "passwordX") must beFalse

      //Confirm the user was inserted properly
      val user = User_data.findUser("user1")
      user.get.user_name must beEqualTo("user1")
      user.get.email must beEqualTo("email@test1.com")
      user.get.password must beEqualTo("password1")
      user.get.edits must beEqualTo(0)
      user.get.reports must beEqualTo(0)
      user.get.active must beTrue
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This code will pass as written, however it shouldn't.  If I uncomment the first test case inside the running block to test that my findAll() function should be a length of 1 it will fail immediately.  However, if I change this to use a persisted PostgreSQL DB on my machine, it will still fail immediately, but when I look at the PostgreSQL DB, my user_data table has the single evolution applied insert in it, and the play_evolutions table has the entry for my evolution and is marked as state = "applied" and last problem = "".

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

(P.S., I am a first time poster, but will do my best to accept an answer as soon as possible for those willing to lend their help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*** UPDATED ***

As Jakob stated, the reason evolutions are failing is probably because the SQL written for MySQL is incompatible with H2DB.  You can solve this by using a separate MySQL for testing as per the original answer, or put H2DB into MySQL compatibility mode which may fix the problem (see [Fixtures in Play! 2 for Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421976/fixtures-in-play-2-for-scala/12445815#12445815)).

Comment: That does not make any sense. If you specify another name for the in memory database, then the connection requests should also be extended with that name. On top of that, you would need a db.test entry in your configuration. If you don't take those steps you will just use the 'default' database anyway. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: I think something is wrong here -- I'm getting the same result that EECOLOR feared.  My test is using the default database, rather than a fresh in-memory database.

Comment: ...If I remove the "test" parameter from inMemoryDatabase(), then the test goes against H2, but the evolution didn't run.  Same for setting my default database to H2 (evolution doesn't run)

Comment: The reason for evolutions not running in memory could be that the SQL in the evolutions files are not compliant with H2. Just becasue all the SQL is valid in MySQL does not mean it is valid in H2. I would suggest using liquibase instead of evolutions...

Comment: Also watch out for using member names that interfer with SQL in your models, for example evolutions in tests fail if you have members named 'group', 'order' etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in play framework 2.0

https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/295-20test-testhelpers-method-evolutionfor-do-wrong-if-fakeapplication-with-inmemroydatabase

Comment: Todd, I don't use Play currently as I was running across too many bugs and/or undocumented behaviors for the quick project I was working on.  I'm not sure if I can transfer a question to you, or allow you to choose the proper accepted answer, but I'm happy to let you take over this question somehow if you feel my accepted answer is no longer accurate.

Comment: Thanks, William Thurston.  I was thinking of posting a new question, but first I want to try this out on the latest release candidate for play framework 2.1.

Comment: ...I still have not upgraded to play 2.1.  It's not a trivial migration, and there are more pressing items in my backlog.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with evolutions and H2 is that H2 is not compliant with everything you can do with  postgres or MySQL for example. So evolutions will run fine in prod but fail in test. I had this problem in a project and eventually solved it by simply not using evolutions and instead use liquibase for the DB stuff.

Or one needs to make sure that the sql you write can be run on H2. In that case evolutions will work fine. I dont remember exactly what the problem with H2 was (something about indexes i think)